# Rename SFTP file after reading it

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-component, mule-connector

I want to read file using SFTP connector and then want to change its name.
This is my SFTP connector -

```
<sftp:connector preferredAuthenticationMethods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" name="SFTP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SFTP" outputPattern="file1Temp.txt"/>
```

My SFTP inbound-endpoint is -

```
<sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="${a.host}" port="${a.port}" path="${a.inputpath}" user="${a.user}" password="${a.pw}" responseTimeout="10000" pollingFrequency="600000"  doc:name="SFTP">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="file1.txt" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

Here, my file name is "file1.txt" and I want to change its name to "file1Temp.txt".

Answer (score 0):

The SFTP connector in Mule 3.x doesn't allow operations on files like rename out of the box. You can follow the method in this KB Article to implement it: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-rename-file-with-the-SFTP-connector